# Show hidden div on a:hover in IE6 - nothing happening

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, web

**My situation:**

I have a three-tier navigation structure where hovering over an item in the secondary level should show a div, which contains the tertiary level.

I have included a screenshot to help illustrate this:

[image: Three level navigation]

The markup I'm using to create this is (sanitised) roughly as below:

```
  <menu class="secondary-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
         One
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
         <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </menu>
```

When you hover over 'Level 2', the 'Tertiary Level' div should appear. To do this, I use CSS such as the below:

```
   menu.secondary-nav .dropdown-menu {display: none;}
   menu.secondary-nav a:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}
```

**My problem:**

In IE6, when I hover over 'Level 2', nothing happens. This is only a problem in IE6 - all other browsers work fine. Is there something wrong with my CSS selectors?

Many thanks.

Comment: The way the markup is layed out, it shouldn't work in any browser. `dropdown-menu` is not the child of `menu.secondary-nav`. You can try changing the menu element to a div for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the great [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Just add to your html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This will make ie6 suport `:hover` on all elements like in [this demo](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/hover.html).

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support `:hover` on a list item. You'll have to shim with javascript.